# xDB SC 8 to SC9 migration and custom facets

Tags: xdb, xconnect, migration

Is there any existing documentation on how to migrate custom facets from SC8 xDB contacts to SC9 using the migration tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/xDBDataMigrationTool/v2.0.1/adding-custom-data/facets/index.html

This will explain how to determine the data to migrate, how to write the components to store your data, how to map the data from MongoDB to xConnect Contact facets and how to use the needed pipelines.